# Instagram embeds are slow or do not load at all

Tags: instagram, social-networking, instagram-api

I notice that when a story is getting a lot of attention on instagram the images and videos embeded on my site load more slowly.  I assume this is because of instagrams infrastructure.  Does anyone else experience this?  And is there a way around it such as a short code that uses an API to directly retrieve the asset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with the `iframe` embedding, like this :

```
<iframe src="https://www.instagram.com/p/BHP6Zm_Drrs/embed" width="400" height="480" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
```

This url will allow you to create an embed using any Instagram photo url

https://www.picodash.com/instagram/embed#https://www.instagram.com/p/BHP6Zm_Drrs/

Comment: How is this different from:  <blockquote class="instagram-media" data-instgrm-captioned data-instgrm-version="7" style=" background:#FFF; border:0; border-radius:3px; box-shadow:0 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.5),0 1px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.15); margin: 1px; max-width:658px; padding:0; width:99.375%; width:-webkit-calc(100% - 2px); width:calc(100% - 2px);">XXX</blockquote> <script async defer src="//platform.instagram.com/en_US/embeds.js"></script>  With regard to load time?

Comment: In other words both are using the instagram infrastructure to serve the images right?  So won't they both experience the same problems?  Or maybe Picodash is using a custom API to query the image so at least the infrastructure would not be experiencing the load only the image serving which could result in a better preformance?

Comment: the one you are using will first get a script from Instagram and then generate an iframe and embed it on page, the one I gave is directly putting iframe on your page. Instagram originally was giving this direct iframe embed code.

Comment: This approach doesnt work because of the new eu policy... it gives me the error Refuse to display 'URL'  in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'DENY'. Same Error for the facebook embed